# how to handle so much multiple value strings

Tags: database-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple values in lookup fields](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10204/multiple-values-in-lookup-fields)

i have a table has about 27 fields are just strings 
and every one of them have multiple values 
for example itemType Field have more than 10 possible values and the user may insert more

i made a tables called properties with those fields (Id, Key, Value) to store those values 
but now i'm confused wither i should use just the (Id)s and reference them in the original table (i think it's no good to put 27 relationships) or doing something else which i don't know what is it exactly

any better ideas or is it ok to continue like this

thanks

Comment: Do you mean that each of the 27 fields can contain multiple strings at the same time or do you mean that they each can contain one value that can be any of ten possible values?

Comment: Also, does each field have it's own set of possible values or do all 27 fields draw from the same 10 possible values?

Comment: @Leigh Riffel yes as you said 
 each one can contain one value that can be any of ten possible values
and
each field have it's own set of possible values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question best we would need to a whole lot more specifics about what you are doing and what the kinds of value are going into each of the fields.

In general though since more values can be added to each set of possible values, a seperate table is advisable.  Unless the fields have overlap in their possible values it would be better to have each set of possible values as a seperate table.  In Oracle these could be Index Organized Tables.